# Problems installing libraries via pip after installing Python 3.12

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

today I installed the new Python 3.12 on my Ubuntu 22.04 from the ppa repository **ppa:deadsnakes/ppa**, everything works, but when I try to install some library with the command **python3.12 -m pip install somelibrary**, I get the following error

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 165, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 285, in run
    session = self.get_default_session(options)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 75, in get_default_session
    self._session = self.enter_context(self._build_session(options))
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 89, in _build_session
    session = PipSession(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 282, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 157, in user_agent
    setuptools_dist = get_default_environment().get_distribution("setuptools")
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/__init__.py", line 24, in get_default_environment
    from .pkg_resources import Environment
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/pkg_resources.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2164, in <module>
    register_finder(pkgutil.ImpImporter, find_on_path)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
```

Any suggestions why this is happening?

EDIT: This problem doesn't exist when I use venv, it seems to me that the problem is that pip uses /usr/lib/python3 instead of /usr/lib/python3.12

Comment: Not all modules that were available in 3.11 (and before) are currently available in Python 3.12

Comment: Can reproduce with `3.12.0-1+jammy1` from deadsnakes.

Comment: I edited the question text, have a look

Comment: @DarkKnight Could you clarify what you mean? Are you talking about the fact that distutils was removed from the standard library? Or do you think this has to do with somelibrary not having a 3.12 distribution on PyPI? This does not appear to be the latter, since it's an internal error inside the bundled pip

Comment: @Brian61354270 All I know, as stated, is that some modules (e.g., pyqt5) cannot currently be installed on 3.12. I didn't research exactly *why* - I just know it doesn't work and that it's something that's being "worked on". It is my suspicion (possibly unfounded) that other modules available through PyPi are not yet 3.12 ready

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77364550/attributeerror-module-pkgutil-has-no-attribute-impimporter-did-you-mean)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`python3.12 -m ensurepip --upgrade` fixed my problem!
[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77364602/22307474)

Comment: ensurepip not found in my case.

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I did:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py
```