# no module found named pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip

When i installed Python 3.12 on Windows. I am following this link (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/). It says pip 24.0 already installed but Powershell or Cmd could not see pip. When i enter pip --version it says no module found pip. Did you face a similar problem like this?

I already tried this [Problems installing libraries via pip after installing Python 3.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77238856/problems-installing-libraries-via-pip-after-installing-python-3-12).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error running 'pip install': "ImportError: No module named pip"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363022/error-running-pip-install-importerror-no-module-named-pip) 
Otherwise, can you add explicitly which commands you write and what output you get?

Comment: Update latest PIP version 24.0 Released: Feb 3, 2024.

Comment: `py -m pip install pip --upgrade`  Successfully installed pip-24.0

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.